# Converting CSV Datetime to an Integer

Tags: python, csv, datetime

My csv file contains dates formatted as:

```
10/3/1946 0:00:00
4/4/1947 0:00:00
```

I would like to know the values in the csv file which occur past, say `12/18/1957 0:00:000`?

To do the comparison, I assume I would need to convert it to a number, for example, `10/3/1946 0:00:00` would be `17078.00`.

Is there a built in way to do that?

Comment: Why not actually compare everything as datetimes, using `strptime`?

Comment: I thought it would be easier to do it this way, because I also need the "number of days elapsed" since a certain date.

Comment: You may convert dates with `strptime` and them calculate difference `date1 - date2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you convert the dates in the csv file into a `datetime` format. This is done by taking the string and using [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to convert it into a `datetime` object. The function takes a format string allowing you to tell it how your date string is formatted. For example `%Y` tells it to expect a four digit year.

First create a datetime to compare against e.g. `after_date`. It is then possible to compare the two dates as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime            
import csv

after_date = datetime(1957, 12, 18)
print "Entries after {}".format(after_date)

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    for row in csv.reader(f_input):
        row_date = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

        if row_date >= after_date:
            print "{} - {}".format(row[1], row_date)
```

This assumes the date you are trying to compare against is in the first column i.e. `row[0]`. So for example, if you had a csv file which looks like:

```
10/3/1946 0:00:00,row1
4/4/1947 0:00:00,row2
4/4/1957 0:00:00,row3
12/19/1957 0:00:00,row4
1/1/1958 0:00:00,row5
```

The script would display the following information:

```
Entries after 1957-12-18 00:00:00
row4 - 1957-12-19 00:00:00
row5 - 1958-01-01 00:00:00
```